# Mapping mod_jk to application with different name from alias

Tags: mod-jk

We have an internet app called X which is being replaced by a new app called Y.

We use Tomcat instances fronted by Apache to serve X and Y, with communications through mod_jk. There is one Tomcat hosting X and another hosting Y.

X and Y have been installed on our production servers - X is being used by our clients, while Y is going through final testing:

```
JkMount /x loadbalancer-x
JkMount /x/* loadbalancer-x
JkMount /y loadbalancer-y
JkMount /y/* loadbalancer-y
```

(*let's ignore the security-through-obscurity aspect of this!*)

When the time comes for Y to go into production, is there a way to map the old URL to the new application, so that `www.mysite.com/x` would point to the new application instead of the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would work if there was an application called x deployed on
>   loadbalancer-y. That's the problem - the new app as a different name,
>   but the bosses want the URL to stay the same. I'm trying to find a way
>   to tell JKMount to request application Y when the URL X us requested.

This is the reason why the [`Context`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) element exist.

1. Pointing `/x` URL prefix to the new worker `loadbalancer-y`:

   ```
   JkMount /x loadbalancer-y
   ```
2. Assuming that the new app's name is `newname`, create a `Context` in
   your `<Host>` element, something like this:

   ```
   <Host name="your.domain.name"  appBase="webapps"
               unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
               xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
       <Context path="/x" docBase="newname"/>
   </Host>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing `JkMount /x loadbalancer-y` wouldn't work?

Comment: It would work if there was an application called x deployed on loadbalancer-y. That's the problem - the new app as a different name, but the bosses want the URL to stay the same. I'm trying to find a way to tell JKMount to request application Y when the URL X us requested.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than globally JkMount'ing it, why not create a /x directory entry in httpd and just JkMount loadbalancer-y, then point loadbalancer-y at the actual application rather than the tomcat root.